# Retrieve the used size of a Sharepoint site by using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, size

I've tried to retrieve the used size of a SharePoint online site by using Graph API (/sites/{siteId}/drive)
However, the used size in quota of the drive is always 0B.
So, I wonder that can we retrieve the size of a SharePoint online site by using Graph API?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the SharePoint Rest API? If so does  `https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/site/usage` also return a StoragePercentageUsed value of zeto?

Comment: Hi, tks for your answer. However, I also would like to get size of a SharePoint site (sub site, top site,... include size of list/attachment items in list). Do we have anyway to get this information? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think site resource in ms graph has such a property that could indicate the size. Is that acceptable to use PowerShell?

- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/04/sharepoint-online-get-storage-size-quota-report-using-powershell.html

BR